# Write a string as binary data to file - C

Tags: c, binary-data

I want to write a string as binary data to a file.
This is my code:

```
FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("test.dat","wb"); // w for write, b for binary
fprintf(ptr,"this is a test");
fclose(ptr);
```

After i run the program and open the file test.dat, i read "this is a test" but not the binary data i want. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be somewhat confused; all data in typical computers is binary. The fact that you opened the file for binary access means it will have e.g. end-of-line conversions done, it doesn't change the interpretation of the data you write.

You're just looking at binary data whose representation is a bunch of human-readable characters. Not sure what you expected to find, that is after all what you put into the file.

The letter 't' is represented by the binary sequence `01110100` (assuming an ASCII-compatible encoding), but many programs will show that as 't' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad decodes the binary data and shows ASCII equivalent code for it.

If you need to see the binary equivalent of the stored data then use hex viewer softwares and open your file in it.e.g. WinHex.

Comment: So the code i used here to save the string as binary data is in fact correct?